# Is there a way to update BottomNavigationBarItems?

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

I am new flutter and been trying to work with the `BottomNavigationBar`. Thing is, i made the bar as i required but i need it to update its items when a `Switch` is set to true but can't manage to find a work around.

I have two `List<BottomNavigationBarItems>` that have the two different navBar items which i assign to a third List that contain the active one depending on the switch state. This variable is the one setting the items in my navbarItem but a `setState()` doesn't seems to re build the navBar.

Is there a way to update the items or do i have to make my own kind of navBar with other widgets ?

[Non Ready Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LxdK.png)

[Ready Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8tse.png)

```
List<BottomNavigationBarItem> nonReadyBottomItems = [
//some items
];
List<BottomNavigationBarItem> readyBottomItems = [
some other items
];
List<BottomNavigationBarItem> = nonReadyBottomItems;

Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Switch(
            value: switchConnect,
            onChanged: (bool boolean) {
              setState(() {
                switchConnect = boolean;
              });
            }),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int i) {
          setState(() {
            pageIndex = i;
            if (switchConnect) {
              activeItems = readyBottomItems;
            } else if (!switchConnect) {
              activeItems = nonReadyBottomItems;
            }
          });
        },
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: activeItems,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You create state full Bottom Navigation Bar for change the state of widgets.

Open bottom sheet

```
InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                isScrollControlled: true,
                builder: (context) {
                  return ModalBottomSheet(

                      );
                });
          })
```

Stateful bottom sheet

```
class ModalBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
 _ModalBottomSheetState createState() => _ModalBottomSheetState();
}

 class _ModalBottomSheetState extends State<ModalBottomSheet>
  {
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

// TODO: implement build
return Wrap(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      margin:
          EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
      child: Column( 
       Widgets(),
      
        )
      )
    ],
  );
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out why the setState() wasn't working. Seems like the there was some problem with the assignment of the activeItems variable so it wasn't changing the bar since there was nothing new.

So setState actually work on a BottomNavBar !